# Inner Join "Invalid Object Name"

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run this sql script but it keep on giving me this error

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
```

Invalid object name 'transaction_details'.

Here is my code and the contents of my other table:

my select query

```
SELECT transaction_details.transaction_id,transaction_status.transaction_id
FROM transaction_details
`INNER JOIN transaction_status
On transaction_status.transaction_id = transaction_details.transaction_id
WHERE transaction_status.status_of_transaction = 'pending'
```

The tables I wanted to join:

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [transaction_id]
      ,[user_id]
      ,[product_id]
      ,[job_description]
      ,[printing_process]
      ,[quantity]
      ,[transaction_date]
      ,[discount]
      ,[total]
      ,[shipping_date]
  FROM [MejOnlineManagementDB00].[dbo].[transaction_details]

    SELECT TOP 1000 [transaction_id]
          ,[user_id]
          ,[product_id]
          ,[status_of_transaction]
      FROM [MejOnlineManagementDB00].[dbo].[transaction_status]
```

I'm pretty sure my names is correct I don't know what is causing the error.

Comment: Is there a more back quote `\`` in your first query? Typo?

Comment: Looks like just a typo. Select the database that you want to use from the dropdown if you're using an IDE. Else tell mysql to `USE MejOnlineManagementDB00;`

Comment: @KaeL thankyou I did that.It was set to `master` after I've change it to my MejOnlineManagementDB00 it work.

Comment: @rainalasa, adding it as an answer if it helped you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like just a typo.

Select the database that you want to use from the dropdown if you're using an IDE. Else, tell mysql to [USE that database](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/use.html).

```
USE MejOnlineManagementDB00;
```

Also you can just include the database name in your query:

```
SELECT D.transaction_id
    ,S.transaction_id
    FROM MejOnlineManagementDB00.transaction_details AS D
    INNER JOIN MejOnlineManagementDB00.transaction_status AS S
        ON S.transaction_id = D.transaction_id
    WHERE S.status_of_transaction = 'pending'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a backtics at the beginning of the inner join  (remove idt)

```
SELECT transaction_details.transaction_id,transaction_status.transaction_id
FROM transaction_details
INNER JOIN transaction_status
On transaction_status.transaction_id = transaction_details.transaction_id
WHERE transaction_status.status_of_transaction = 'pending'
```